# Что правильно? Тире или запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

"Не переживай – завтра у нас будет целый день для этого".

Comment: Целый день - для того, чтобы что-то сделать или чтобы переживать?

Comment: Чтобы сделать, поработать.

Comment: А как читатель должен догадаться?

Comment: Пожалуйста: "Жаль, что сегодня не успеем собрать лодку. Не переживай – завтра у нас будет целый день для этого".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Не переживай – завтра у нас будет целый день для этого.**

Всё вполне логично.

Пауза нужна, чтобы обозначить **пояснительные отношения**, поэтому нужно использовать не запятую, а  **двоеточие или тире**.

Двоеточие – это основной знак для обозначения пояснительных отношений, когда **причина указана во второй части предложения**.

В то же время **тире может заменять двоеточие,** если пояснение носит присоединительный характер (в этом случае в устной речи делается меньшая по длительности пауза).

Comment: Исправлено неверно: ставим тире для обозначения присоединительного характера пояснительных отношений, а основным пояснительным знаком является двоеточие.

Comment: Jasmin, будьте хозяином на этой территории, комментарии ни к чему..

Comment: А как отклонить редактирование?

Comment: Не проще ли отредактировать еще раз, чем искать способ отклонить  редактирование?

Comment: Выберите кнопку Править и — вперёд.

Comment: Так тире или двоеточие?

Comment: Вы поставили тире, и это верное решение.  Другой возможный знак - двоеточие,  но  к разговорному стилю и данной конструкции предложения больше подходит тире. Это более универсальный и распространенный знак, в то время как двоеточие  чаще используется  в книжной речи и в тех случаях, когда оно действительно необходимо. Для обозначения причинно-следственных отношений двоеточие необязательно.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще-то выбор между тире и двоеточием (раскрывается причина гипотетического непереживания), а запятая как бы и не к месту вовсе...

Comment: Отнюдь. Запятая может вполне быть перед тире.